# How to search in XML? (PHP)

Tags: php, xml, xpath, search

I am working on a word application. I'm trying to get values from XML. My goal is getting the first and last letter of a word. Could you help me, please?

```
<!--?xml version='1.0'?-->
<Letters>
    <Letter category='A'>
        <FirstLetter>
            <Property>First letter is A.</Property>
        </FirstLetter>
        <LastLetter>
            <Property>Last letter is A.</Property>
        </LastLetter>
    </Letter>
    <Letter category='B'>
        <FirstLetter>
            <Property>First letter is B.</Property>
        </FirstLetter>
        <LastLetter>
            <Property>Last letter is B.</Property>
        </LastLetter>
    </Letter>
    <Letter category='E'>
        <FirstLetter>
            <Property>First letter is E.</Property>
        </FirstLetter>
        <LastLetter>
            <Property>Last letter is E.</Property>
        </LastLetter>
    </Letter>
</Letters>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
$word = "APPLE";
$alphabet = "ABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPQRSŞTUÜVWXYZ";
$index = strpos($alphabet, $word);
$string = $xml->xpath("//Letters/Letter[contains(text(), " . $alfabe[$rakam] . ")]/FirstLetter");
echo "<pre>" . print_r($string, true) . "</pre>";
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear - you've said what you're trying to do, and included some incomplete code (you haven't shown where `$xml` is defined), but you haven't explained what happens that you need help with.

Comment: I mean that find the first letter. Then find its properties from XML.

Comment: Yes, but what do you need _our_ help for? This isn't a free code writing service, we're not going to simply write a program for you, but we're happy to help if you have a specific problem. Have a look at [ask]

Comment: Actually I don't want to full code. Also not need it. I'm developing an application. I need only right "$string" value in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The letter is in an attribute named 'category'.

```php
$word = "APPLE";

// bootstrap DOM
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// get first and last letter
$firstLetter = substr($word, 0, 1);
$lastLetter = substr($word, -1);

// fetch text from property elements
var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate(
     "string(/Letters/Letter[@category = '$firstLetter']/FirstLetter/Property)"   
  ),
  $xpath->evaluate(
     "string(/Letters/Letter[@category = '$lastLetter']/LastLetter/Property)"   
  )
);
```

Or in SimpleXML

```php
$word = "APPLE";

$letters = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$firstLetter = substr($word, 0, 1);
$lastLetter = substr($word, -1);

// SimpleXML does not allow for xpath expression with type casts
// So validation and cast has to be done in PHP
var_dump(
  (string)($letters->xpath(
    "/Letters/Letter[@category = '$firstLetter']/FirstLetter/Property"
  )[0] ?? ''),
  (string)($letters->xpath(
    "/Letters/Letter[@category = '$lastLetter']/LastLetter/Property"
  )[0] ?? '')
);
```